# How can I get the top value in a colormap?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to expand the colormaps that I get on Dicom images and for that I need the top value of their gray intensities. How can I do this in code?

```
image_data, image_colormap= dicomread('dicomfile.dcm');

max(image_colormap)
```

returns `[]`

:-/

Comment: is it a color dicom image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
I = dicomread('dicomimg.dcm');
max(I(:))
```

for truecolor/grayscale image, the map is empty

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html),

> [X,map] = dicomread(...) returns the image X and the colormap map. **If
>   X is a grayscale or true-color image, map is empty.**

For a grayscale image, you can use `max(image_data(:))`